# Numpy TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types,

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have the following data frame and list values

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df_merge = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['a', 'c', 'e'],
               'column2': ['b', 'd', 'f'],
               'column3': [0.5, 0.6, .04],
               'column4': [0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
               })

bb = ['b','h']
dd = ['d', 'I']
ff = ['f', 'l']
```

I am trying to use np.where and np.select to instead of IF FUNCTION:

```
condition = [((df_merge['column1'] == 'a') & (df_merge['column2'] == df_merge['column2'].isin(bb))),((df_merge['column1'] == 'c') & (df_merge['column2'] == df_merge['column2'].isin(dd))), ((df_merge['column1'] == 'e') & (df_merge['column2'] == df_merge['column2'].
isin(ff)))]

choices1 = [((np.where(df_merge['column3'] >= 1, 'should not have, ','correct')) & (np.where(df_merge['column4'] >= 0.45, 'should not have, ','correct')))]

df_merge['Reason'] = np.select(condition, choices1, default='correct')
```

However, when i try to run the code line of choices1, i get the following error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Im am not sure if we can use np.where in choices as mentioned above.

np.where should be applied for both columns. Expected output as below:

```
df_merge = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['a', 'c', 'e'],
               'column2': ['b', 'd', 'f'],
               'column3': [0.5, 0.6, .04],
               'column4': [0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
               'Reason': ['correct, should not have', 'correct, should not have', 'correct, should not have'],
               })
```

Any help / guidance / alternative is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First length of `condition` list has to be same like `choices1`, so last condition is commented (removed) for length 2.

Then if compare by `isin` output is condition (mask), so compare with column has no sense.

Last problem was need list of length 2, so replaced `&` to `,` and removed parantheses in `choices1` list for avoid tuples:

```
condition = [(df_merge['column1'] == 'a') & df_merge['column2'].isin(bb),
             (df_merge['column1'] == 'c') & df_merge['column2'].isin(dd)
#             (df_merge['column1'] == 'e') & df_merge['column2'].isin(ff),
             ]

choices1 = [np.where(df_merge['column3'] >= 1, 'should not have','correct'),
            np.where(df_merge['column4'] >= 0.45, 'should not have','correct')]

df_merge['Reason'] = np.select(condition, choices1, default='correct')
print (df_merge)
  column1 column2  column3  column4           Reason
0       a       b     0.50      0.7          correct
1       c       d     0.60      0.8  should not have
2       e       f     0.04      0.9          correct
```

Comment: Thank you. However, i need to check in both columns and then provide a comment for each row. How can that be done?

Comment: @Shri - Can you add expected output DataFrame? Maybe also is necessary change data for [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Question Updated with expected output

Comment: @Shri - Do you check link? Because if all values are same, then it is not [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also outpu tis no `correct` or `should not have`, similar like in my answer? (maybe another values)